# Javascript onclick object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been trying to figure this out for hours

Here is the error I'm getting:

[image: error]

I don't understand what is causing the error, any insight would be appreciated!

And here is my code, disregard the smarty syntax:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
        {include file='header/header.tpl'}
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <center>
                <img src="" style="height: 70px;">
            </center>
            <div class="form-signin">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" style="font-size: 10pt;" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" style="font-size: 10pt;" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Login" data-loading-text"Login" id="login" onClick="login();" style="outline: none;">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            function login() {
                alert('asdf');
            }
        });
    </script>
    {/literal}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `login` is not in scope. Add the event _in JavaScript_ not in the markup.

Comment: How is it not in scope? It looks to be in scope

Comment: Aside from the scope issue, both the `login` function and the input with `id="login"` can be references with `login`, so you're ending up with a name-collision here.

Comment: Do `$('#login').click(login)` or add a "submit" event to the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move login outside of the ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        function login() {
            alert('asdf');
        }
    });
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            alert('asdf');
        }
</script>
```

The problem was login only existed inside the ready function scope. Example

```
function say() {

   function hello() {
       alert("hello");
   }

   // call hello inside the say scope
   hello(); // this displays the alert
}


say(); // this will show the alert

hello(); // error function is not defined. because it is out of scope
```

Answer (score 0):

The `login` function is created inside the `ready` event handler, so it only exists inside that function.

Put it outside the event handler, so that it exists in the global scope, then you can call it from the click event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function login() {
      alert('asdf');
    }

    $(function() {
    });

</script>
```

Consider using the `submit` event of the form instead of a click event on the button. Then it will also work if the user submits the form by pressing enter in a field. Also consider binding the event in the script instead of in the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // if you want to stop the submit and do something else'
        alert('asdf');
      });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious why a function declared with  jquery "ready" isn't able to be called. I tested it in jsbin, you're definitely right, but why is that?

Comment: @thomas: Javascript has function scope, which means that variables that you declare inside a function only exist inside that function. That also goes for functions, so when you declare a function inside another function, it can't be accessed outside of it.

Comment: is there any way around that? I'm just curious, clearly there is no need to do it any other way than you suggest. `onClick="$.login()"` didn't work for me, but is there anyway to access functions stored in other functions?

Comment: @thomas: Not unless the outer function exposes the inner function, either by putting a reference to it in a global variable, or returning a reference to it so that you can assign the return value to a global variable.

Comment: Hmm..not sure I understand I understand. Would you mind providing an example for one or both? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas: Here are examples of exposing the inner function: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/1pfL8ys0/